# Filter google sheet based on two columns

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I want to use the filter option and filter data based on two columns. The filter should throw results of only those rows where column 1 value < column 2 value.

Tried using conditional format option in the Filter (drop down at top right) option but something does not seem to be correct. Can someone please help with the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with these [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) and [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/94590/filter-numbers-in-one-column-based-on-whether-they-are-higher-than-in-another-co). I've tried replicating your issue using the formula: `=A2<B2`.

Here is my sheet:

[image]

Filtered using the formula: `=A2<B2`:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't work for me and I think I may know the reason why. So my coloumn 2 has data that is obtained from the function GOOGLEFINANCE.  So when I apply the filter you have mentioned, 0 rows show up. Do you think it is because the cell is using a reference ?